# How to compact sequence of letters?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to compact the sequence "AABBAABBAC" to "(A2B2)2AC".

My Python code is already printing "A2B2A2B2C", but I can't manage to do the "(A2B2)2" grouping part.

This is my code:

```
def compact_rep(seq):
    comp=[]
    i=0
    cont=1
    for i in range(0,len(seq)-1):
        if seq[i] == seq[i+1]: 
            cont+=1 
        else:
            comp.append(seq[i]) 
            if cont>1:
                comp.append(cont)
            cont=1
    if cont>1:
        comp.append(seq[i]) 
        comp.append(cont) 

    else:
        comp.append(seq[i+1])
    return ''.join([str(x) for x in comp])
```

How can I make it work to also do the second grouping?

Comment: Have you tried to solve that part of the problem yourself? Can you show your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an efficient algorithm you should look into suffix trees/arrays.

But if you need this for relatively short strings, then you could use a regular expression with a back reference, leading to relatively simple code:

- Look for the longest repetitions first, maximising the number of repetitions, using a greedy match
- Use a callback function to make the replacement
- Repeat the above for as long there are matches
- Make sure to exclude digits and parentheses from matches

This may yield nested results like "((AB)2)2", which can be further simplified (to "(AB)4"). This should be verified and replaced after each successful replacement above.

Code:

```
import re

def compact_rep(seq):
    def repl(m):
        opening = m.group(1)
        first = m.group(2)
        repetitions = m.group(3)
        closing = m.group(4)
        wrapper_repeat = m.group(5)
        repeats = 1 + len(repetitions) // len(first)
        if len(first) > 1:
            first = '(' + first + ')'
        if opening and wrapper_repeat:
            # simplify
            repeats = repeats * int(wrapper_repeat)
            return first + str(repeats)
        return opening + first + str(repeats) + closing + wrapper_repeat

    seq2 = '';
    while seq2 != seq:
        seq2 = seq
        seq = re.sub(r'(\(?)([^\d()]+)(\2+)(\)?)(\d*)', repl, seq2)
    return seq

res = compact_rep('BBBACACBDBDACACBDBDACACBDBDACACBDBDAC')
print(res) # B3((AC)2(BD)2)4AC
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but when i run this code, if my seq is "ABABABAB", it prints "((AB)2)2" and the ideal would be (AB)4

Comment: I adapted the code to deal with this (a second time). Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: it works perfectly! thank you so much!

Comment: sorry to bother you, but i'm having a little trouble understanding why you use "repeats = 1 + len(repetitions) // len(first)"
could you shortly explain why? thank you

Comment: Let's say you have "ABCABCABC", then `first` will be "ABC", and `repetitions` will be the "ABCABC" that follows it. The 1 represents the occurrence that `first` accounts for and `len(repetitions) // len(first)` calculates how many more occurrences there are in `repetitions`, in this example: 2. So in total: 3.